# XML Java : Summing a group of attributes

Tags: java

I'm working on a little project using XML, DOM and Java and I can't sum the transaction total for each clients. Any tips? Thanks a lot!

Here's the XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<list> 
  <client name="Yvan Orzwitz"> 
    <transaction total="30" />
    <question>Where do you live?</question>
    <transaction total="90" /> 
  </client> 
  <client name="Tifanny Jonas"> 
    <transaction total="45" /> 
    <transaction total="5" /> 
    <question>Where do you live?</question>
    <transaction montant="98" /> 
  </client> 
</list>
```

Here's my Java code so far :

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;

public class transactions {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = 
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder parser = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = parser.parse(args[0]);
    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement(); 
    NodeList nl = root.getElementsByTagName("client");
    NodeList nl2 = root.getElementsByTagName("transaction");

    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); ++i) {
      Element client = (Element) nl.item(i);
      System.out.println("Client name : " + client.getAttribute("name"));
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one tip: instead of getting all `<transaction>` elements from the root DOM node,  use the [getChildNodes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getChildNodes()) method on each `<client>` Element node--this will return only the transactions that pertain to that client.